# Error when trying to round values of a column to nearest in R

Tags: r, dplyr, rounding, data-manipulation

This is the column of the data that I want to analyse:

```
dput(head(IdentifiedCars$ConnectionTimeHours, 10))
c(12.0102777777778, 0.00305555555555556, 6.29361111111111, 3.34416666666667, 
1.43361111111111, 2.54472222222222, 3.86694444444444, 14.3997222222222, 
1.3175, 1.75888888888889)
```

I am trying to round the values of a column (ConnectionTimeHours) in my dataframe (IdentifiedCars) to the nearest integer with this script:

```
df <- IdentifiedCars %>%
  round(ConnectionTimeHours, 0) %>%
  group_by(ConnectionTimeHours) %>%
  summarise(counts = n())
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting this error:
**Error in function_list[i] :
object 'ConnectionTimeHours' not found**

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Call to $ConnectionTimeHours in the IdentifiedCars dataframe. (IdentifiedCars$ConnectionTimeHours

Comment: `IdentifiedCars %>% count(ConnectionTimeHours  = round(ConnectionTimeHours, 0))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Round within *mutate* or within *group_by*, see example:

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(grp_drat = round(drat, 0)) %>% 
  group_by(grp_drat) %>% 
  summarise(count = n())

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(grp_drat = round(drat, 0)) %>% 
  summarise(count = n())

# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#    grp_drat count
#      <dbl> <int>
# 1        3    13
# 2        4    18
# 3        5     1
```

Or use *count()* instead of *n()*:

```
mtcars %>% 
  count(grp_drat = round(drat, 0))
#   grp_drat  n
# 1        3 13
# 2        4 18
# 3        5  1
```